# how to replace the number in excel .1 with .0/24 in the very IP address

Tags: excel

For example, we have a 160 IP address In every IP address end with.1 and I want to replace that last .1 with .0/24

Example: 
77.218.250.1
37.250.182.1
77.218.243.1

These replace with 
77.218.250.0/24
37.250.182.0/24
77.218.243.0/24

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,2)=".1",LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2) & ".0/24",A1)
```

[image]